# MySQL: How to pull most recent records of a table? (minor join complexity)

Tags: mysql

I am building a player tracker app for myself and have hit a snag trying to select all the latest entries for a list of stats that player has.

I'm trying to keep the query complexity low because I'm unsure what my resources will be once I put it on the web.

What I am trying to do with the tables/query included below is  by a player ID, select the most recent records of EACH STAT TYPE that player has. (I will detail the result below the code)

I have been trying things like DISTINCT and MAX but have failed.

```
-- the offensive query
SELECT player_id, stat_types.label, value, scraped_at
FROM stats s1
JOIN stat_types ON stat_types.id = type_id
WHERE scraped_at = (
    SELECT scraped_at
    FROM stats s2
    WHERE s1.player_id = s2.player_id
    ORDER BY scraped_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
AND player_id IN (300)    

-- SOME TABLE SUMMARIES/ABSTRACTS
players
+-----+------------+
| id  | first_name |
+-----+------------+
| 300 | Andrew     |
+-----+------------+

stat_types
+----+-----------------------+
| id | label                 |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | goals                 |
|  2 | assists               |
|  3 | points                |
|  . | ...                   |
+----+-----------------------+

stats
+----+---------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| id | type_id | player_id | value  | scraped_at          |
+----+---------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |       300 | 1.0000 | 2019-08-16 16:22:48 |
|  2 |       2 |       300 | 1.0000 | 2019-08-19 16:22:48 |
|  3 |       3 |       300 | 2.0000 | 2019-08-19 16:22:48 |
|  4 |       3 |       300 | 4.0000 | 2019-08-20 17:34:48 |
|  5 |       1 |       300 | 7.0000 | 2019-08-20 16:22:48 |
+----+---------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

Ideally, I would get a return like this...

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
| player_id | label   | value   | scraped_at          |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
|       300 | goals   |  7.0000 | 2019-08-20 16:22:48 |
|       300 | assists |  1.0000 | 2019-08-19 16:22:48 |
|       300 | points  |  4.0000 | 2019-08-20 17:34:48 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

But using the query above, if a player has ONE stat that is the most recent, all of the others that don't match are omitted like this:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
| player_id | label   | value   | scraped_at          |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------|
|       300 | points  |  4.0000 | 2019-08-20 17:34:48 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: `ORDER BY player_id DESC`

Comment: A SQL Fiddle with schema and sample data would be helpful

Comment: Your where is comparing to only one date so it is only returning the data that matches the max date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `stats` to `stat_types` and use NOT EXISTS to get the latest values:

```
select
  s.player_id, t.label, s.value, s.scraped_at
from (
  select s.* from stats s
  where s.player_id = 300
  and not exists (
    select 1 from stats
    where player_id = s.player_id and type_id = s.type_id and scraped_at > s.scraped_at
  )  
) s inner join stat_types t on t.id = s.type_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e3db2631da475f234d4b6f8df3d9cde9).
Results:

```
> player_id | label   | value | scraped_at         
> --------: | :------ | ----: | :------------------
>       300 | goals   |     7 | 2019-08-20 16:22:48
>       300 | assists |     1 | 2019-08-19 16:22:48
>       300 | points  |     4 | 2019-08-20 17:34:48
```

Comment: This totally works for what I needed thank you!

Could you please help me understand the AND NOT EXISTS subquery?
Is it running this to check if there is no record older than the one pulled?

Comment: This is exactly what it does.